# How to use ranges from 2 sheets within Filter function

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, modulo

I need to add additional ranges to the Filter functions. I thought using **Concat** would do the trick but it's just repeating values and not giving me the desired output.

Original Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(
            FILTER('OFF FIGURE'!D11:Z184, MOD(COLUMN('OFF FIGURE'!D11:Z184) , 5)=0)=C11, 
            FILTER('OFF FIGURE'!E7:Z184, MOD(COLUMN('OFF FIGURE'!E7:Z184)+1, 5)=1), ),,9^9)), 
            "(?i) "," " ), "  ", ", "), "^$", "OPEN"))
```

Desired Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(
            FILTER('OFF FIGURE'!D11:Z182, MOD(COLUMN('OFF FIGURE'!D11:Z182) , 5)=0)=C7, 
            FILTER('OFF FIGURE'!D7:Z178, MOD(COLUMN('OFF FIGURE'!D7:Z178)+1, 5)=1), ),,9^9)), 
            "(?i) "," " ), "  ", ", "), "^$", "OPEN"),
 ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(
            FILTER(FASHION!D12:Z183, MOD(COLUMN(FASHION!D12:Z183) , 5)=0)=C7, 
            FILTER(FASHION!E7:Z178, MOD(COLUMN(FASHION!E7:Z178)+1, 5)=1), ),,9^9)), 
            "(?i) "," " ), "  ", ", "), "^$", "OPEN"))))
```

Desired outcome would be to get the values from both the Off Figure AND Fashion sheets.
Obviously **Concat** is not what I want...

I added the formula on this spreadsheet and got pretty much the same results I did when I tried using the **Concat** function.

Link to test spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d0SXXQxbd9mPQSjr6olDIzVdL6Gg8FWZtA9oVDQx9bo/edit#gid=1966451697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY({IF(
 FILTER(FASHION!D12:Z183, MOD(COLUMN(FASHION!D12:Z183) , 5)=0)=C3, 
 FILTER(FASHION!E7:Z178, MOD(COLUMN(FASHION!E7:Z178)+1, 5)=1), ); IF(
 FILTER('Off Figure'!D12:Z183, MOD(COLUMN('Off Figure'!D12:Z183) , 5)=0)=C3, 
 FILTER('Off Figure'!E7:Z178, MOD(COLUMN('Off Figure'!E7:Z178)+1, 5)=1), )},,9^9)), 
 "(?i) "," " ), "  ", ", "), "^$", "OPEN"))
```

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY({IF(
 FILTER(FASHION!D12:Z183, MOD(COLUMN(FASHION!D12:Z183), 5)=0)=C5, 
 FILTER(FASHION!D6:Z177, MOD(COLUMN(FASHION!D6:Z177)+1, 5)=0), ); IF(
 FILTER('Off Figure'!D12:Z183, MOD(COLUMN('Off Figure'!D12:Z183), 5)=0)=C5, 
 FILTER('Off Figure'!D6:Z177, MOD(COLUMN('Off Figure'!D6:Z177)+1, 5)=0), )},,9^9)), 
 "(?i)bay ", ), " ", ", "))
```

[image]

Comment: That didn't seem to work...
I'll edit the question to include a screenshot of the output and also add a link for a test page

Comment: @Michael please edit your sample sheet and include example of desired final result

Comment: @Michael answer updated

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I can see that it works on the test sheet so I'm obviously going to mark it as the correct solution.
I'm having issues on the production spreadsheet though. I'm guessing because I have hidden rows to select multiple photographers if applicable. 
So I have to tinker around with it a little. But thanks again!